# Using finditer() with string from request.FILES

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to get my head around this problem and have tried to find something on the internet, to no avail. I am uploading a file (< 2.5MB) which I read from request.FILES and decode it to `utf-8` which is saved in a variable. I then need regex to do its thing with that string so I can iterate through the regex matches.

The weird thing is that `re.finditer()` returns its callable iterator `<callable_iterator object at 0x05D49350>` but with no results, however, if I `open('file.txt', 'w', newline='')` and `open('file.txt', 'r')`, the `re.finditer()` works.

```
req_file = request.FILES['file']
log_string = req_file.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
req_file.close()

sect_re = re.compile(
    r'\*(?P<title>[^*]+)\*\s\*+\s{2,3}(?P<body>(?:(?!\*+\n).+\s+(?!\*+\n))+.+|)',
    re.M
)
re_results = re.finditer(sect_re, log_string)  # loop through the regex results
```

I've tried this also (I forgot `chunks()` was an option with an `UploadFile`. Thanks to [dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten) for that) but it still does not work when it gets to `re.finditer()`:

```
req_file = request.FILES['file']
log_string = ""
for c in req_file.chunks():
    log_string += c.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

sect_re = re.compile(
    r'\*(?P<title>[^*]+)\*\s\*+\s{2,3}(?P<body>(?:(?!\*+\n).+\s+(?!\*+\n))+.+|)',
    re.M
)
re_results = re.finditer(sect_re, log_string)  # loop through the regex results
```

> Following on from both code examples above, as an edit:

```
for s in re_results:
    #  do something with 's' (re.match) of each result.
```

> The above for loop is never entered (which is the problem)

`log_string` prints to console any time the file is read and it looks OK.

`re.search()` with a different regex string will work using `log_string` in the same compile.

Just to make it clear, the Regex string above works perfectly fine and it is most definitely not the problem here. The problem is using `re.finditer()` on a string that was saved using `request.FILES['file']`.

For example, the below works perfectly fine but seems a little long winded just to get a regex method to work:

```
req_file = request.FILES['file']
log_string = req_file.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
req_file.close()
with open("file.txt", 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(log_string)

new_log_string = ""
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_log_string = f.read()
sect_re = re.compile(
    r'\*(?P<title>[^*]+)\*\s\*+\s{2,3}(?P<body>(?:(?!\*+\n).+\s+(?!\*+\n))+.+|)',
    re.M
)
re_results = re.finditer(sect_re, new_log_string)  # loop through the regex results
```

> Following on from the above code, as an edit:

```
for s in re_results:
    #  do something with 's' (re.match) of each result.
```

> The above for loop is successfully entered and executes the code on the matches.

Is it to do with it being read from memory? Am I missing something very obvious here?

> EDIT

I know the recommended way is to go through the chucks which I am doing in the code outside of Stackoverflow because it works.

I'm actually using a `FileField` within a `with` statement because the file is written using the `save()` method of the model (it works):

```
with log_file.file_field.open(mode='r') as f:
     for c in f.chunks():
         log_string += c
```

This is why I know writing then reading a file works, however, it's just that I came across this and wanted some insight. I know it's there and it's driving me insane :)

If you want something to test the regex with:

```
*************
*First Title*
*************

Lots and lots and lots of text
that fill this section up
to tell you things about something          


**************
*Second Title*
**************

Some Text goes here


*************
*Third Title*
*************

Lots of text goes here
with CRs etc
     and tabs
```

> Output from re.DEBUG:

```
LITERAL 42
SUBPATTERN 1 0 0
  MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
    NOT_LITERAL 42
LITERAL 42
IN
  CATEGORY CATEGORY_SPACE
MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
  LITERAL 42
MAX_REPEAT 2 2
  IN
    CATEGORY CATEGORY_SPACE
SUBPATTERN 2 0 0
  BRANCH
    MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
      ASSERT_NOT 1
        MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
          LITERAL 42
        LITERAL 10
      MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
        ANY None
      MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
        IN
          CATEGORY CATEGORY_SPACE
      ASSERT_NOT 1
        MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
          LITERAL 42
        LITERAL 10
    MAX_REPEAT 1 MAXREPEAT
      ANY None
  OR

  0. INFO 8 0b1 7 MAXREPEAT (to 9)
       prefix_skip 1
       prefix [0x2a] ('*')
       overlap [0]
  9: LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 11. MARK 0
 13. REPEAT_ONE 6 1 MAXREPEAT (to 20)
 17.   NOT_LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 19.   SUCCESS
 20: MARK 1
 22. LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 24. IN 4 (to 29)
 26.   CATEGORY UNI_SPACE
 28.   FAILURE
 29: REPEAT_ONE 6 1 MAXREPEAT (to 36)
 33.   LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 35.   SUCCESS
 36: REPEAT_ONE 9 2 2 (to 46)
 40.   IN 4 (to 45)
 42.     CATEGORY UNI_SPACE
 44.     FAILURE
 45:   SUCCESS
 46: MARK 2
 48. BRANCH 56 (to 105)
 50.   REPEAT 45 1 MAXREPEAT (to 96)
 54.     ASSERT_NOT 12 0 (to 67)
 57.       REPEAT_ONE 6 1 MAXREPEAT (to 64)
 61.         LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 63.         SUCCESS
 64:       LITERAL 0xa ('\n')
 66.       SUCCESS
 67:     REPEAT_ONE 5 1 MAXREPEAT (to 73)
 71.       ANY
 72.       SUCCESS
 73:     REPEAT_ONE 9 1 MAXREPEAT (to 83)
 77.       IN 4 (to 82)
 79.         CATEGORY UNI_SPACE
 81.         FAILURE
 82:       SUCCESS
 83:     ASSERT_NOT 12 0 (to 96)
 86.       REPEAT_ONE 6 1 MAXREPEAT (to 93)
 90.         LITERAL 0x2a ('*')
 92.         SUCCESS
 93:       LITERAL 0xa ('\n')
 95.       SUCCESS
 96:   MAX_UNTIL
 97.   REPEAT_ONE 5 1 MAXREPEAT (to 103)
101.     ANY
102.     SUCCESS
103:   JUMP 5 (to 109)
105: branch 3 (to 108)
106.   JUMP 2 (to 109)
108: FAILURE
109: MARK 3
111. SUCCESS
```

Comment: It `req_file` a big file (> 2.5 MB)? It's recommended to loop through `req_file.chunks()` instead of `read()`

Comment: it's < 2.5MB. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: `re.finditer()` returns a generator, so you'd need to call `iter/next/for ... in ...` on it.

Comment: It seems to be when the file has been decoded from bytes. If it's just read it's fine.